# Why does Nearest not return both equally distant values?

Tags: nearest

Define the following three vectors:

```
a = {0., 0., 0.};
b = {-0.5`, 0.4330127018922193`, 0.25`};
c = {-0.5`, 0.`, 0.`};
```

Note that the distance from a to c is the same as from b to c.

```
Norm[a - c] == Norm[b - c]

True
```

Also

```
DistanceMatrix[{a, b}, {c}]

{{0.5}, {0.5}}
```

And yet when I call **Nearest** it returns only one of the two (b).

```
Nearest[{a, b}, c]

{{-0.5, 0.433013, 0.25}}
```

Why is that?
I have played with WorkingPrecision but that does not help.

Based on a comment below, I have a work-around of the following form:

```
Nearest[{a, b}, c, DistanceFunction -> (Round[Norm[#1 - #2] 10^6] &)]

{{0., 0., 0.}, {-0.5, 0.433013, 0.25}}
```

Thanks to all who took the time!

But speaking of taking the time, the modified DistanceFunction causes the function to run at least 10x slower.
Here is a function that is almost as fast as the original but behaves as expected.

```
MyNearest[points_, tests_] := Block[{dm, mins, pos},
  dm = DistanceMatrix[tests, points];
  mins = Min /@ dm;
  pos = MapThread[Position, {dm, mins}];
  points[[#]] & /@ (Flatten /@ pos)
  ]

MyNearest[{a, b}, {c}]

{{{0., 0., 0.}, {-0.5, 0.433013, 0.25}}}
```

Comment: `DistanceMatrix[{a, b}, {c}] // FullForm` tells you why... C.E. pointed this out in their answer, but they deleted it. Don't know why.

Comment: I restored the answer now. I feel like I haven’t been able to get to the bottom of all the ifs and whys, though

Comment: `MyNearest` is much slower for me than @C.E.'s custom `DistanceFunction`.

Comment: Here's a one-bit rounding difference for which `MyNearest` does not work: ``SeedRandom[15];
aa = a;
bb = RotationTransform[Pi/3, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}], c][a];
MyNearest[{aa, bb}, {c}]`` -- compare with `Norm[aa - c] == Norm[bb - c]`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to get all the points that are equivalent to being `Equal` in distance:

```
Nearest[{a, b}, c,
 {All,
 (1 + 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance*$MachineEpsilon) *
   EuclideanDistance[First@Nearest[{a, b}, c], c]}]
```

Calls `Nearest` twice unfortunately, but it's about as fast as @C.E.'s on the toy example and much faster on 1000 points.

Answer (score 3):

If you copy the numbers returned by `DistanceMatrix` into new cells, you can see that they are not exactly the same. The first number copies as 0.5 and the other as 0.49999999999999994.

If you take the outputs `Norm[a - c]` and `Norm[b - c]` and copy them into new cells then they will be copied as 0.5.

In any case, `0.49999999999999994 == 0.5` returns true. So it doesn't just come down to the fact that the numbers are slightly different, it also matters that different functions use different definitions of equivalent.

This is a possible work-around:

```
Nearest[{a, b}, c, DistanceFunction -> (Round[Norm[# - #2], 10^-10] &)]
```

Comment: It appears that `Nearest` does not "compare with tolerance."  Be nice if there were such an option.  Also, a custom `DistanceFunction` usually makes `Nearest` less efficient, not that it matters on the toy example. +1 all the same.